# how do i get all parent rows of some specific row in single Table

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

http://prntscr.com/bl6oeo[image: Structure of table]

I can get all child of category with id 1 with follwing query..

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',')
FROM (
  SELECT @pv:=(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM files WHERE parent_id IN (@pv)
  ) AS lv
  FROM files
  JOIN (
    SELECT @pv:=1)tmp WHERE parent_id IN (@pv)
  ) a
```

can anybody tell me how can we get all parents of some row for example 4th row

Comment: what do you mean by "all parents". In row 4 as far as I can see you got one parent. select * from files f left join parentTable pt on f.parent_id=pt.id where f.id=4

Comment: i meant the parent rows of 4th row which are 3rd and 1st..however this question is answered now..thanks for your attention dear

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer... :)

```
SELECT T2.id, T2.title
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM files WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 4, @l := 0) vars,
        files h
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN files T2
ON T1._id = T2.id
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```